# Error while working with template cache: Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig/29)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian, upgrade

my first post, please excuse any mistakes.

I've recently upgraded to the current latest version of phpmyadmin (5.1.1) on a Debian Server running Nginx and MariaDB. These are my versions:

- Debian 10 up to date
- MariaDB 10.3.31
- Nginx 1.14.2
- PHP 7.3.19

After the installation, phpmyadmin is working, but showing me the following error on each screen:

```
Error while working with template cache: Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig/29).
```

That specific folder seems to have the same owner, group, and permissions as mos of the folders in the same location.

Any idea why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it deleting twig file, it generates itself when you open phmyadmin.
I don't know the reason of the problem but it works.